# Cognito User Pool - Are refresh tokens tied to client ID?

Tags: amazon-cognito

While doing some cross-team work the other day attempting to get an API endpoint in place to facilitate the use of refresh tokens, I was a bit stumped as to why I was getting an "Invalid Refresh Token" error back when I would try the InitiateAuth or AdminInitiateAuth actions when attempting to use the REFRESH_TOKEN or REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH flows.

In the .NET API we are transitioning over to Cognito, I was using one Client ID.  We were also using another client ID for a starter project that we could hit to get JWTs back.  From what I can tell, the Client ID is tied to the refresh token, which is why I was getting the invalid token error.

Can anyone confirm that has a bit more experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, it is tied to a client id.

Source: I work on the Cognito team.